How to generate $0$ from $1$ and $-1$ in group of integers under addition operation?
I was following the Algebra book by Gallian. It mentioned that
"The set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ under ordinary addition is cyclic. Both $1$ and $-1$ are generators".
This part is easy to understand.
My doubt: How are we going to generate $0\in \mathbb{Z}$ with the help of $1$ and $-1$?
Kindly help. Any hint or suggestion is heartily welcomed.
Thanks in advance for the help.

If you're having trouble producing $0$ from $1$ and $-1$, it's not clear to me that you've really understood the first sentence. What do you understand it to mean, in ordinary English?

@BrianTung we need to produce every element with the help of only one element, right? No combination. 0 is 1+(-1). I have this doubt

A group always includes an identity element and inverses for all elements.

I was going to say this, but @Karl beat me to it. (Actually, I was going to ask you what you thought the definition of a group was, but this cuts to the point a bit faster.)

ok, I understood. Thanks

The definition of a group generator, or a generating set, includes inverses, e.g.
$$\langle S\rangle := \{ x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_k \mid \forall k, j  : x_j \in S \text{ or } x_j^{-1} \in S \}.$$
Thus $\langle 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$ since the additive inverse of $1$ is $-1$.

If a group G is cyclic with generator x, then G also can be generated by $x^{-1}$. Since Z is generated by 1, the meaning of the notation $1^k$ is the same as $1 \cdot k=k$. Hence, $1^{0}=0$. So, $0 \in \langle 1\rangle$.


How are we going to generate $0\in \mathbb Z$ with the help of $1$ and $-1$?

The cyclic group generated by $g$ is $\{kg\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.
So take $g=1$ (or $-1$), and take $k=0\in\mathbb Z$ to get $0$.

The standard "first" definition of the subgroup generated by a set $S$, so $\langle S\rangle\leq G$, is the minimal subgroup containing the set $S$. This definition is useful because it eliminates the confusions here. Indeed, combining this definition combines with standard properties of subgroups gives us that the identity will always be contained in $\langle S\rangle$. In particular, for $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $0\in\langle 1\rangle$ and $0\in\langle -1\rangle$.
As subgroups are closed under inverses, $x\in \langle S\rangle$ if and only if $x^{-1}\in\langle S\rangle$. In particular, for $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\langle 1\rangle=\langle -1\rangle$.
From here it is not hard to show that the elements of $\langle S\rangle$ may be viewed as products of elements from the set $S\cup S^{-1}$, rather than just from $S$. It is a (very) common misconception that $\langle S\rangle$ is the product of elements from $S$. This is however the case for finite groups, which is a nice exercise to do.

I honestly do think it's a good question (at least, for a beginner) ,  even though your statement that you understand $1,-1$ being generators is easily enough becomes nonsense.
While, other than $0,$ all the elements have infinite order,  only $1$ and $-1$ generate the whole group. Taking $1,$ you can add it to itself all you want.    But,  as in the other answer,  you can also take it away.
